# Python2.7: Saving executed program steps and read them one by one

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi

I am experiencing the following problem. I would like to integrate a feature into my Rasberry Pi controlled RC-car which brings this RC-car back to its starting point. To do this it must record every command given to the car by the user and at the end it should execute them again except in reverse in order to arrive back at its starting point.

I have done a lot research about `strings` and `arrays`, but none of them seem to be a good way to obtain this desired behavior.

So my question; is there any way to do this?

Comment: *"Do I just have the wrong idea of solving this problem?"* - imagine it was told to drive in a square, ending up back where it started. Now you tell it to return to its starting point. What should it do?

Comment: Right now I just want to add this feature without regarding how to use it. That'll be the next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a `stack` data structure. It follows the "first-in, last out" rule. In Python it is really easily to use Lists (just like arrays) as a stack by using `append` and `pop`. Here is a code snippet to give you an idea of how it could work:

```
directions = []
directions.append('forward')
#execute command here
directions.append('right')
#execute command here then turn car 180 degrees
#at this point directions = ['forward', 'right'] now you need to just pop the commands to execute
issueCommand(directions.pop()) #sends 'right'
issueCommand(directions.pop()) #sends 'forward'
```

Comment: What does it do when it has reached the beginning of the list? Does it send a 'nil' or anything like that?

Comment: If you try to use `.pop` on an empty list you'll get an `IndexError` exception. Best to use `len(directions)` before you pop to make sure it isn't empty.

Comment: I've tried and used it in an if-clause but it always just uses the last string and after that it says the list is empty... :/